# Remove Hyphens from Query & Database Lookup Field

Tags: php, sql, magento, search, matching

I recently setup a Magento store which draws products from various external feeds - most we have no control over. I've run into a problem in that our customers are searching our site using queries without hyphens and our products description (both SKU and title) contain one or more. You would think that Magento could handle such an issue but unfortunately no results show.

I've been into fulltext.php, where I believe a solution would probably begin, but have been unable to figure this out. In addition, I also attempted to fix the opposite issue where the product description had no hyphen but the search query did but the following code failed to do anything when added to the top of 'function prepareResult'.

```
$queryText = str_replace('-',' ',trim($queryText));
```

Comment: And what "fail" is that? What error are you getting? Unless this is a "guess what error it is!" type of question, please help us help you.

Comment: 'Failed to do anything' simply meant the addition of the code above made no difference to the output. I think that's pretty self-explanatory.

Tonight has been a learning experience, but despite my efforts I've not found a solution that is appropriate for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yup, I definitely misread your question.